# Get right of string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a control file that has different College names and count of students in political science.

```
Clark=1200
UMASS=500
UPenn=200
```

I want to go through this control file and check if a pattern exists and want to print everything after the pattern until the end of the line using PowerShell.
This is what I have:

```
Get-Content "c:\temp\CTRL.txt" | Select-String -Pattern 'UPenn='
```

If I do this I only get Upenn=200 but I want to get the number 200.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-match` and `-replace` operators:

```
$pattern = '^UPenn='
(Get-Content 'C:\temp\CTRL.txt') -match $pattern -replace $pattern
```

The `-match` operator selects lines beginning with "UPenn=", and the `-replace` operator removes that string from the selected lines.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass the contents of your file into a `Select-String`, it can handle files on its own. The command returns an object which has a Matches property which contains all the found matches, this in turn contains the a value property which has the found text. If you modify the regex so that it uses a look behind then the value will contain 200. Something like this:

```
(Select-String -Path 'C:\temp\CTRL.txt' -Pattern '(?<=UPenn=)\d+').Matches.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer a different approach and if all keys in the file are different, you can use [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-6). This approach will work because your keys and associated values are delimited by `=`.

```
(Get-Content 'c:\temp\CTRL.txt' | ConvertFrom-StringData).UPenn
```

`ConvertFrom-StringData` will return a `Hashtable` object of key-value pairs. Each key's value can be accessed using the `hashtable.key` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match on the right side of the equals for each line in the file:

```
( Select-String -Path C:\temp\CTRL.txt -Pattern '(?<=.+=).*').Matches.Value
```

`Select-String` selects the string from each line in the file using the regex pattern. The expression uses a positive lookbehind to find the characters before and including the `=`, and match on any characters beyond.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more dynamic access to the contents of the file, you could load the contents of the file into a `Hashtable` with the following expression: `^(?<key>[^=]+)=(?<value>.*)$`

Example:

```
$ctrl = @{}
$result = Get-Content 'c:\temp\CTRL.txt' | Select-String '^(?<key>[^=]+)=(?<value>.*)$'

Foreach ($match in $result.Matches) {
    $ctrl[$match.Groups['key'].Value] = $match.Groups['value'].Value
}

Write-Output $ctrl['Clark']
Write-Output $ctrl['UMASS']
Write-Output $ctrl['UPenn']
```

Answer (score 0):

..and yet another approach using `-split`:

```
((Select-String -Path 'C:\temp\CTRL.txt' -Pattern '^UPenn=').Line -split '=', 2)[1]
```